# InvalidOperationException - 'Template' property cannot be set in the current element's Template

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, listviewitem

I'm trying to override the default `ListviewItem` in `ListView` with my custom own, so i used `GetContainerForItemOverride()`. It worked as expected, but when i try to override the default `template` it throw the following exception:

> InvalidOperationException: ''Template' property cannot be set in the current element's Template'

Am i missing anything here?

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:StockViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Null}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="60px" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:StockViewItem}">
                    <Grid Background="Transparent">
                        <Border
                            x:Name="ContentHost"
                            Margin="0"
                            Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding DefaultBackground}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}">
                            <Grid>
                                <GridViewRowPresenter x:Name="gridrowPresenter" Content="{TemplateBinding Property=ContentControl.Content}" />
                                <ContentPresenter
                                    x:Name="contentPresenter"
                                    Content="{TemplateBinding Property=ContentControl.Content}"
                                    Visibility="Collapsed" />
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="GridView.ColumnCollection" Value="{x:Null}">
                            <Setter TargetName="contentPresenter" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="ContentHost" Property="Background" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:StockViewItem}, Path=ActiveBackground, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource SelectedTemplate}" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" />
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
                        </MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="False" />
                                <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" />
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter TargetName="ContentHost" Property="Background" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:StockViewItem}, Path=HoverBackground, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                        </MultiTrigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: You have a Trigger on the IsSelected property with a Setter for the Template property in `ControlTemplate.Triggers`. Move that Trigger (or perhaps all) to `Style.Triggers`.

Comment: @Clemens Ok, i must be really exhausted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted by Clemens, i had the `Template` setter in a trigger inside the `Template` itself instead of the `Style` triggers.